# Can p:menu support lazy loading?

Tags: primefaces, menu, lazy-loading

I have a primefaces tree with a toolbar (some menus triggered by buttons) and a contextmenu. The menus are depending from the selection in the tree.

On a select event I set the menus to null and do an update of the toolbar and of the context menu. This causes the menu to be re-initialized, even if maybe is not necessary (the user don't necessary will open the menu). Is there a way to implement a sort of lazy menu?

```
<p:menu model="#{myBean.myMenuModel}" overlay="true" trigger="myMenuButton" my="left top" at="left bottom" autoDisplay="false">
</p:menu>
```

---

PF7.0.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, version info and what menu component? please... But I think the answer is no or certainly not easily... Check the documentation.

Comment: I have also the impression it is not supported...